# How do you open a console application?

Tags: c#

How do you open a console application from a "button" on a windows form in another window.  Examples would be awesome.

Say this is the code:

```
namespace something
{
  class form1 : form
  {
    private void buttonPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //I want whatever it would be to be put right here for this is the button that would be pressed
    }
  }
  class ConsoleApplication
  {
    public static void Method()
    {
      console.writeLine("hello World!");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Process.Start(@"console_app.exe");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Process.Start("path to ConsoleApp.exe")`

[Process.Start(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx)